# Why this simple DAE equation is not solved with 'DSolve'? Is that a BUG?

Tags: differential-equations

I need to solve the following system of two Differential-Algebraic Equation (DAE) :

```
{-b'[t] == a[t] b[t], a[t] == 2 b[t] - 4}
```

When I wrote the code of solving this system using `DSolve` according to the [Help of DAE Solving in Mathematica](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/SolveADifferentialAlgebraicEquation.html) , I get literally nothing !

My code is :

```
DSolve[{-b'[t] == a[t] b[t], a[t] == 2 b[t] - 4}, {b[t],a[t]}, t]
```

The answer I've got from Mathemtica 12.2:

```
DSolve[{-b'[t] == a[t] b[t], a[t] == 2 b[t] - 4}, {b[t],a[t]}, t]
```

But when I solve the algebraic part of my system by my self (with some simple algebra) and convert this DAE into ODE (Just by replacing the `a[t]` from `a[t] == 2 b[t] - 4` into the first equation `-b'[t] == a[t] b[t]`) , now the problem becomes :

```
DSolve[{-b'[t] == (2 b[t] - 4) b[t]}, {b[t]}, {t}]
```

then the problem solves ! The answer of Mathematica is :

```
{{b[t] -> (2 E^(4 t))/(E^(4 t) + E^(2 C[1]))}}
```

So the problem is solvable by Mathematica ! That said , I emphasized that this problem is very very simple and I wanted to show you that the Mathematica itself knows the answer ! Now , my question is why the Mathematica can not solve the DAE system mentioned above giving me the answer that it already knows ?!  Is this a bug ?!

Comment: It's possible `DSolve[]` just doesn't know what to do with that DAE. That said, this is a simple enough example that it is reasonable to expect `DSolve[]` should know something; please report this to Support.

Comment: it seems to work only on additive terms. Using the example in docs, if you replace `x'[t]+y[t] == 0` by `x'[t]*y[t] == 0` then it also no longer works. Same with your case.

Answer (score 5):

The tutorial [Differential-Algebraic Equations (DAEs)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DSolveDifferentialAlgebraicEquations.html) very cagily says that `DSolve` can solve ***linear*** DAEs but is silent whether it can solve nonlinear equations. Everything hints that (currently) `DSolve` cannot solve nonlinear DAEs.  One can see that linear DAEs are a special case in `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions@DSolve`DSolveDispatchFirstOrderODEs `` (search for "DAE" or `DSolveLinearFirstOrderDAEs`). This area of DEs is new to `DSolve` in V12, so perhaps WRI intends to expand its functionality (soon?).

As a workaround, I can suggest differentiating the DAE:

```
DSolve[{
  -b'[t] == a[t] b[t],
  D[a[t] == 2 b[t] - 4, t],      (* differentiate algebraic equation *)
  a[t] == 2 b[t] - 4 /. t -> 0}, (* condition to constrain degree of
                                    freedom added by differentiating
                                    the algebraic equation           *)
 {b, a}, t]

(*
  {{b -> Function[{t}, -((2 E^(4 t))/(-E^(4 t) + E^(4 C[2])))],
    a -> Function[{t}, -((4 E^(4 C[2]))/(-E^(4 t) + E^(4 C[2])))]}}
*)
```